# Ajax with codeIgniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

This is my view file index.php

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset=Cp1252">
    <title>Demo Ajax</title>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="<?php echo             base_url().'assets/js/jquery-1.4.2.js';?>"></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#bttHello').click(function(){
        var fullname = $('#fullname').val();
        alert(fullname);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            data:{fullname: fullname},
            url: '<?php echo site_url('ajax/hello');?>',
            success: function(result){
                $('#result1').html(result);
            }
          });
       });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    Name <input type="text" id="fullname">
    <input type="button" value="Hello" id="bttHello">
    <br>
    <span id="#result1"></span>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and this is my controller file ajax.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Ajax extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('index');
    }
    public function hello(){
        echo 'hiiiiiiii';
        $fullname = $this->input->post('fullname');
        echo 'Hello'.$fullname;
    }
}
```

But when i click submit button nothin happens no error is shown , i think it is not redirected to the url i have given in ajax code. Please help me out to get directed to the controller and then the function hello through ajax.

Comment: Please help me if anyone has got the answer

Comment: Do you have any error in your browser's developper tool ? Are you sure `site_url('ajax/hello')` generates a valid link ?

Comment: Change into you ajax's --
url: "<?php echo base_url();?>ajax/hello",
also use the latest jquery instead.

Comment: I tried using php echo base url , but the same thing is happening

Answer (score 1):

do you familiar with debugger tools ?
if no, you need to debug it first to check the problem, you can use chrome developer tools (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) 
or you can using [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug) addons

then you can test again and see what happend with your jquery code in console

here an example steps how to use debug tools using chrome

1. open your web using chrome
2. using shortcut key (F12) to activated developer tools
3. then test your application, if there is any error in your jquery/javascript code, the console will display it.

Hope this help you.

Comment: I tried debugging but no errors are shown and i am not able to identify where i m going wrong

Comment: you need to make sure your url is correct, to make it able do debug you save the url inside the variable then debug with console.log(yoururl)

here an example:

`

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#bttHello').click(function(){
        
       var requestUrl = "<?php echo site_url('ajax/hello');?>";
       // then debug here, to make sure your url is correct and not null
       alert(requestUrl);

        $.ajax({
            url: requestUrl, // i just paste the part changed, the other is no changes
          });
       });
    });

Comment: thank u very much Kahfi for your answer , now its working